# Python cannot installing dbus package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I tried many things but I could not install dbus package for python3.

I believe this command install the dbus for python3:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dbus-dbg
```

However I still get this error:

```
>>> import dbus
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'dbus'
```

Comment: I believe this question does not belong here but I really need immediately install this package.

Comment: Why did you install the debug package?

Comment: I couldn't find something else
When I enter this:
sudo apt-get install python3-dbus
It says python3-dbus is already the newest version.

Comment: that means that `python3-dbus` is already installed - you don't need the debug version. Are you sure you're running the Python ***3*** interpreter when you try to `import dbus`? It works fine for me...

Comment: yes I am absolutely sure.

Comment: I wasn't able to install dbus package using pip but {sudo apt-get install python-dbus} worked for me for python2.7. Your comment saved me. Thanks @user3817833

Answer (score 0):

If you work in PyCharm, you can do it by following there steps:

File -> Settings -> Python Interpreter -> + -> dbus-python -> install Package

[picture with steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SGFA.png)

At first I tried to install it with `pip install dbus-python`, but it didn't worked for me.